# how to ignore the data based on specific keywords?

Tags: sql

Want to ignore the row no 2 and 3 which is not have any space based on 2nd table data .
Table 1 like below

```
  No    Name 
    1   kumar unknow raja
    2   kumarunknowraja sameple
    3   kumartradraja testing
    4   kumar trad raja
    5   trad
    6   unknow
```

Table 2

```
Name
unknow
trad
```

Using this query but l am getting all the records `select * from base_tbl where exists (select name from exc_tbl);`

Comment: Your `EXISTS` query is not correlated. If at least one row *exists* in the table `exc_tbl` then *all* the rows in `base_tbl` will be returned. You need to correlate your subquery.

Comment: Wouldn't a standard INNER JOIN with possibly a DISTINCT work here? What about row number 4?

Comment: @Larnu If i tried with cor releated sub query only s.no 5 and 6 will return . But i need 1 and 4 also

Comment: it would be less performant most likely, @DanielG . A correlated `EXISTS` is likely for more performant solution here.

Comment: Presumably you need some pattern matching or string splitting, @Vinoth_S . As such functionality is RDBMS specific, and you're yet to [edit] your question, we can't give you an answer. Though your question really needs some better explanation in it too.

Comment: @Larnu - I want to ignore the 1st table data which does not contain the any space before and after the keyword like 'unknow' or 'trad'.

Comment: Again, without knowing what RDBMS you are using, we *cannot help you*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an ms sql solution. It is an ugly piece of sql though....

```
with data(No,Name ) as(
select 1,   'kumar unknow raja' union all
select 2,   'kumarunknowraja sameple' union all
select 3,   'kumartradraja testing' union all
select 4,   'kumar trad raja' union all
select 5,   'trad' union all
select 6,   'unknow' 
),
param (name) as (
select 'unknow' union all
select 'trad'
),
data2 (No,Name ) as(
select No,data.Name from data
join param on data.name = param.name 
union 
select No,data.Name from data
join param on data.name like ('% ' + param.name + '%')
union 
select No,data.Name from data
join param on data.name like ('%' + param.name + ' %')
)
select * from data2
order by No
```

But it gives you what you want:

[image]